# Systemd and AmbientCapabilities: debugging "Invalid argument" error

Tags: arch-linux, systemd, capabilities

I am running Arch Linux.
My problem originally manifested with Caddy web server, but it is not limited to it. Thus I have a simple unit to troubleshoot with a random binary (capsh):

```
[Service]
ExecStart=/sbin/capsh --print
AmbientCapabilities=CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE
User=nobody
```

I have run strace -f -p 1 which traces PID 1 and its children, so I could see the raw error after starting the unit:

```
prctl(PR_CAP_AMBIENT, PR_CAP_AMBIENT_RAISE, CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE, 0, 0) = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
```

Because of this, I have to resort to sudo setcap cap_net_bind_service=+ep for the Caddy binary and commenting out the capabilities settings in the unit. I am staying with systemd 231, because newer versions error out even though I have setcapped the binary.

What further debugging options do I have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cause was a kernel that was too old! I was using OVH server and it had kernel 3.14. I had not realized the system update does not update the kernel. I followed these http://help.ovh.com/KernelInstall and a bit of these instructions https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=214512